# UnitTest Project's code sync with source?

Tags: unit-testing, xunit

I have a Visual Studio solution named - UnitTestProject, unit test with xunit framework.

Under this solution, a project named - MainProject and MainProject_Test,

The MainProject is the "Real" Source for implementation, the MainProject_Test for unittest, which contain the xunit attribute,Assert etc..

My question is, everytime i make change on MainProject, i have to copy&paste to MainProject_Test, it is not efficient way.

So how did the people reflect the code but retain the attribute or Assertion ?

Another question is, is it any name convention of UnitTest project? MainProject_Test / MainProject.Test or MainProjectTest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MainProject_Test should reference MainProject. It shouldn't have a copy of all its code.

A common naming convention is MainProject and MainProject.Tests, but there are a number of such conventions.

Comment: Thanks Marty Dill, it seem i am got some wrong understanding in unit test. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should reference your main project from your unit test project. Right-click on the references node of the test project in solution explorer to add the reference.

I would name the test project `MainProject.Test`.